# How can I reduce a $2$nd order ODE as $1$ st order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to learn differential equations, I have some troubles with the following $2$nd order ode :

Let

> $$\ddot{x}=-7\dot x +\omega(t)^2x(t) \:, \:\: x(0)=7,\dot x(0)=0$$

Where $\omega$ is a differentiable and periodic function on $\mathbb R$.

So my two questions are : How can I express this ODE as a  $1$ st order ODE ?  And how can I tell if the solution is global ?

Any help would be a lot appreciated. Best wishes.

**EDIT:** As marked in the comment there might be an error in the formula..

How would the same question be answered for

> $$\ddot{x}=-\dot x -\omega(t)^2x(t) \:, \:\: x(0)=1,\dot x(0)=0?$$

Comment: Are you sure about the sign of the last term? $$\ddot x+7\dot x+ω(t)^2x=0$$ would be an oscillator with variable frequency and (a rather large) friction term.

Comment: By the way you may be able to solve this equation with an integrating factor too!

Comment: With that sign you do not get oscillation. If $ω$ is constant you can solve the equation via exponential ansatz and characteristic exponents.

Comment: you should not edit a question (changing it to something really different) after it was answered and accepted by you, you should probably ask another question instead

Comment: The OP changed the question. It's now a completely different question than the original one.

Comment: Please do not change answered questions to a different topic, I rolled it back to your first version. // You need not close an answered question, as that is the first step to deleting it. Setting the check-mark is sufficient notification.

Comment: That was slightly better, but please leave the original content unchanged if the answers become less comprehensible without it. I changed that back and added the modified question as a follow-up section.

Comment: Is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063956/ordninary-differential-equation-global-solution also from your lesson group?

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes but we all have different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of any linear DE with leading coefficient $1$ exists where or as long as the coefficients are continuous. Here that only depends on $ω$, if that function is continuous on $\Bbb R$, then any solution can be extended to the whole of $\Bbb R$, growing in a rule-of-thumb like $$\exp\left(\int_0^r(\sqrt{3.5^2+ω(s)^2}-3.5)ds\right)$$
where the integrand is $ω(s)^2/7$ for small $ω$ and about $(ω(s)-3.5)$ for large $ω$.

---

This estimate follows the WKB approach, try $x=e^U$ to find $u'+u^2+7u-ω^2=0$, $u=U'$, assume the changes in $ω$ and thus in $u$ are slow enough that $u'$ can be neglected (that is the reason for it being hand-wavy or a rule-of-thumb), and solve the quadratic equation for $u$, then integrate. There will be a second solution due to the quadratic equation that is strictly falling and thus not relevant for the growth of the solution.

---

If, as in the second equation $\ddot x+\dot x+ω^2x=0$, the sign of the last term was correct for an oscillation, one would get oscillating solutions of the approximate shape
$$
\frac{e^{-0.5·t}}{\cos\phi_0}·\cos\left(\phi_0+\int_0^t\sqrt{ω(s)^2-0.5^2}ds\right)
$$
if the frequency has a lower bound $ω(t)>0.5$. Here $\phi_0$ was introduced to be chosen so that the initial derivative becomes zero. (This is somewhat superfluous as the formula is an approximation anyway and will quickly deviate, probably first in phase, the amplitude shape remaining valid for a longer time.)

Comment: I added a motivation for the estimate.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Set $y=\dot x$. Then $$\begin{pmatrix}\dot x\\ \dot y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y\\ -7y+\omega (t)x\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\omega (t)^2&-7\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I don't really see where it leads .. where the $\omega^2$ went ?

Comment: @RosaAmbre: Sorry, I misread your equation. I edited my answer.