# Ordninary Differential equation ( global solution )

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I want to check if the equation: $$x''(t)=-3x'(t) + (w(t))^{2}x(t)$$$$x(0)=3\ \&\ x'(0)=0$$ has a global solution knowing that w(t) is periodic and differentiable.

I started First by writing it into two first order differential equations as follows $$x'(t) = y(t)$$ $$y'(t)= (w(t))^{2}x(t) -3y(t)$$$$x(0)=3\ \&\ y(0)=0$$

Now i was trying to calculate a first integral by trying to find a solution for $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{w^{2}x-3y}{y}$$ So that I can either bound the first integral or show that the solution cannot be contained in any compact set as t tends to infinity. However I cannot find the first integral as I couldn't solve the differential equation above. Is my approach correct but hard to solve and is there another way to find a global solution ?

Comment: Does this count as duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063844/how-can-i-reduce-a-2nd-order-ode-as-1-st-order-ode?

Comment: See also "Matthieu equations" to see that there are no easy solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Set $y=\dot x$. Then $$\begin{pmatrix}\dot x\\ \dot y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y\\ -3y+\omega (t)^2x\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\omega (t)^2&-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}.$$

Using [Picard-Lindelof Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) allows you to conclude.

Comment: I cannot see how would i use Picard-Lindelof theorem. And is there a discussion based on the values of w(t) ?

Comment: @idkibebs : Set $A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\omega (t)^2&-3\end{pmatrix}$. Since $\omega $ is continuous and bounded, there is $M>0$ s.t.  $$\left\|A(t)\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}-A(t)\begin{pmatrix}\bar x\\ \bar y\end{pmatrix}\right\|\leq M(|x-\bar x|+|y-\bar y|)$$ for all $x,y,\bar x,\bar y\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: This proves that A(t) is Lipchitz continuous which would imply A is continuous , And hence any maximal solution is global. And that's it, its done ?

Comment: Not really. The function $f(t,x,y):= A(t)\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$ is Globally Lipschitz, and thus, there is a unique global solution to the Cauchy problem. @idkibebs